# Flutter: how to align two elements inside a "row" inside a form?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing an application in Flutter. Create a registration form for users.  I want two elements to be in the same row aligned at baseline level, like this:

[image]

But in my app it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code of the specific line:

```
                            Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    DropdownButton(
                                      hint: Text('Cod.'),
                                      items: codeList,
                                      value: selectedcode,
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          selectedcode = value;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey[600],
                                          fontSize: scalador.setSp(22) * 2.63),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: scalador.setWidth(275) * 2.41,
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              telefono = val;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              hintText: "Telefono"),
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey[600],
                                              fontSize:
                                                  scalador.setSp(22) * 2.63),
                                          validator: (value) {
                                            if (value.isEmpty) {
                                              return 'Por favor ingrese su telefono';
                                            } else {
                                              if (value.length < 8)
                                                return 'El numero de telefono debe tener mas de 8 digitos';
                                            }
                                            return null;
                                          }),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
```

How can I solve this?

---

Edit:

Implement this way of adding Dropdownbutton to textformfield, , as suggested in some answers below

```
TextFormField(
                                    onChanged: (val) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        telefono = val;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: "Telefono",
                                        prefix: DropdownButton(
                                          hint: Text('Cod.'),
                                          items: codeList,
                                          value: selectedcode,
                                          onChanged: (value) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              selectedcode = value;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey[600],
                                              fontSize:
                                                  scalador.setSp(22) * 2.63),
                                        )),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                                        fontSize: scalador.setSp(22) * 2.63),
                                    validator: (value) {
                                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Por favor ingrese su telefono';
                                      } else {
                                        if (value.length < 8)
                                          return 'El numero de telefono debe tener mas de 8 digitos';
                                      }
                                      return null;
                                    })
```

But now it looks like this, when you render the interface

[image]

The DropdownButton does not appear visible in the interface but it does take up your space.  De esta manera;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the TextField by Expanded. Or by Container and set the width on 80/90% of screen and do it for button but for button set the width on 10/20% of screen width.

Answer (score 0):

why use a row when `TextForField` provides you the feature

```
TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefix: //implement the drop down here
                ),
              )
```

Comment: I implemented it, but the detail now is that when I render the select, it doesn't appear visible, I have to touch it to show it.

look at the edition of the question